# remove rows with numerical zero in the second column

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a tab separated file and need to filter the rows with zero value.

```
$ head my_file.txt
id  SRR1385501
chr1:11672:+::chr1:12009:+  0 
chr1:14830:-::chr1:14969:-  8 
chr1:14830:-::chr1:15795:-  0 
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:-  2 
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:-  10
```

I am trying with the command below (awk version: GNU 4.0.2, but it is still removing header)

```
$ awk '$2 !=0' my_file.txt
chr1:14830:-::chr1:14969:-  8 
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:-  2 
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:-  10
```

My desired output is:

```
id  SRR1385501
chr1:14830:-::chr1:14969:-  8 
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:-  2 
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:-  10
```

Comment: Trying both https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk (awk version 20231001) and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/ (GNU Awk 5.2.2), your approach produces the desired output.

Comment: I have GNU Awk 4.0.2, it is removing header, any other command ?

Comment: Try: `awk 'FNR==1 || $2' my_file.txt`

Comment: To debug your problem, please change your script to `awk '{print NR, NF, "[" $0 "]"; for (i=1; i<=NF: i++) print "\t" i, "<" $i ">"} $2 != 0' my_file.txt | cat -A` , run it on exactly the input you show in your question, and then [edit] your question to show it's output.

Comment: According to https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/ that release is 11 years old. Can you upgrade?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using any awk, this will do what you want:

```
$ awk '$2 != "0"' file
id  SRR1385501
chr1:14830:-::chr1:14969:-  8
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:-  2
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:-  10
```

The above assumes your 2nd column always has exactly the string `0` for "numerical zero", not `0.0` or `-0` or `+0` or anything else.

The result you're getting is inconsistent with the way [awk comparisons are supposed to work](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing):

> When two operands are compared, either string comparison or numeric
> comparison may be used. This depends upon the attributes of the
> operands, according to the following symmetric matrix:
>
> ```
> +----------------------------------------
> |           STRING    NUMERIC    STRNUM
> +---------+------------------------------
> | STRING  | string    string     string
> | NUMERIC | string    numeric    numeric
> | STRNUM  | string    numeric    numeric
> +---------+------------------------------
> ```

`$2` should be of type `STRING` for the first line of your input because `SRR1385501` doesn't look like a number to awk, and type `STRNUM` for the rest because all of those other values such as `0` and `8` do look like numbers but awk can't initially tell if you want to use them as numbers or strings.

According to the above table, then, the type of comparison between `SRR1385501` (`STRING`) and `0` (`NUMERIC`) should be `string` and those 2 values are not the same string so the header should be printed. For the rest it's `STRNUM` vs `NUMERIC` which is simply a `numeric` comparison.

I suggest getting a new version of gawk (we're now on 5.3) as yours is out of date and **maybe** it contains a bug, but I highly doubt it as this would be major breakage. More likely there's something about your input file or your script that are different from what you've shown and told us about so far.

Comment: Many many thanks and sincere respect Ed. I really appreciate your help even for my simple problems.

Comment: You're welcome but you really should do what I suggested in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77376951/1745001) so we could help you figure out what the source of your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

the minimal `awk` will be

```
$ awk '$2' file

id  SRR1385501
chr1:14830:-::chr1:14969:-  8
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:-  2
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:-  10
```

this assumes your header will have a second field with nonzero value.

Comment: If that worked then what the OP already has, `$2 != 0`, should also be working.